# run flask app kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, minikube

this might be a silly question but how can i get my https://localhost:5000 working through my flask kuberenetes app to ensure its returning back the right info?

This is my workflow so far:

```
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
$ docker build ...
$ kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml (contains deployment & service)
$ kubectl set image...
```

`kubectl logs...` returns this below: also my pods are up and running so nothing is failing

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/  (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 443-461-677
```

the only thing is when i go to that address in my browser it says the site can't be reached. when i `curl https://localhost:5000` or `curl https://0.0.0.0:5000/` i get a failed to connect error. i feel like my enviroment/set up is wrong somehow. any tips/suggestions? 
thank you!

also heres my deploy.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: test-space
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: "SECRET_KEY"
          value: /etc/secret-volume/secret-key
        - name: "SECRET_CRT"
          value: /etc/secret-volume/secret-crt
      volumes:
        - name: secret-volume
          secret: 
            secretName: my-secret3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: test-space
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 30000
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Python Flask within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646474/how-to-run-python-flask-within-a-docker-container)

Comment: are you exposing your host port to the container? what does your deploy.yaml look like?

Comment: @DavidMaze i have that in my app.run and it still doesn't work sadly :/

Comment: @Skam added it up there! my nodePort is actually 30000 but curling https://localhost:30000 or 80 still gives a failed to connect error for some reason.

Comment: actually, forgot to mention, im exposing port 5000 in my dockerfile

Comment: Your `targetPort` in your service is 9376 but your container is exposed on 5000.  First try changing the `targetPort` to 5000.  Then you can `curl $(minikube service myapp --url)` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blame/master/README.md#L132)

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta thanks! did that but im getting a different error `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` which might mean that fixed my initial question?? anyways ill keep trying

Comment: Change flask to listen on `0.0.0.0`, localhost/127.0.0.1 in container != localhost outside of container.

Comment: @johnharris85 do you mean curling inside the container? and i have app.run(host='0.0.0.0') in there

Comment: Doesn't look like that's taking effect based on your flask output "listening on 127.0.01 etc..."

Comment: sorry forgot to update that, changed it after i posted it

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev added it!

Comment: Are you trying the `curl`s in your post, or the `curl $(minikube service myapp --url)` I suggested when you get that "reset by peer" error?

Answer (score 2):

As you have exposed `Port 5000` in the Dockerfile, you need to expose the same Port in the container in your Deployment. After that, you need to configure your Service to use this Port.

It should look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: test-space
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 5000 #<<<PORT FIXED
        env:
        - name: "SECRET_KEY"
          value: /etc/secret-volume/secret-key
        - name: "SECRET_CRT"
          value: /etc/secret-volume/secret-crt
      volumes:
        - name: secret-volume
          secret: 
            secretName: my-secret3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: test-space
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000 #<<<PORT FIXED
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 30000
```

After that, you can reach you application on `<any-kubernetes-node-IP>:30000`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create service with label selector myapp.
But there is another way you can do curl
by logging into running pod and execute curl from inside the pod.

Just do

kubectl exec -it podname /bin/bash This will open bash shell
Then you can do curl localhost:5000